# Prove convergence by probability.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I am recently studying this theme. How to solve such problems? The answer is clear, but how to prove it? Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_n,...$ i.i.d. Let  $nP(|\xi_1|>n)\rightarrow 0$ and $a_n = E(\xi_1 1_{|\xi_1|< n})$.
Show that
$\frac{\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n}{n} - a_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$

Comment: You can probably find a proof of this somewhere if you look for "Law of Large Numbers"; this is a fairly weak version of LLN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define $$X_{k, n} = \xi_k \mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi_k| < n\}},\ 1\le k \le n.$$ Also define $T_n = n^{-1}\sum_{k=1} \xi_k$ and $T'_n = n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n X_{k,n}.$

Note, since $\xi_k$'s are i.i.d., we have $$a_n = E(X_{k,n}) = E(T'_n).$$
The key idea is to apply Chebyshev's inequality to give an upper bound on $P(|T'_n - a_n|>\varepsilon),$ and to observe that $T_n$ and $T'_n$ are equal with high probability.

More precisely, note that $$P(T_n \neq T'_n) \le \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_{k,n}\neq \xi_k) = n P(|\xi_1| > n) \to 0.$$

On the other hand, Chebyshev's inequality gives
\begin{align}
P(|T'_n - a_n|>\varepsilon) 
&\le \varepsilon^{-2} n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^n E(\xi_k^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi_k| < n\}}) \\
&\le \varepsilon^{-2}n^{-2} \sum_{k=1}^n E(\xi_1^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi_1| < n\}}) \\
&\le \varepsilon^{-2}n^{-1} E(\xi_1^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{|\xi_1| \le n\}}).
\end{align}
Now observe that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} E \left({\xi_1}^{2} \mathbf{1}_{\{|{\xi_1}| \leq n\} }\right)
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} E \left({\xi_1}^{2} \mathbf{1}_{\{k-1<|{\xi_1}| \leq k\}}\right)\\ 
&\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2} P(k-1<|{\xi_1}| \leq k) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k} 2 j\right) P(k-1<|{\xi_1}| \leq k) \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} 2 j \sum_{k=j}^{n} P(k-1<|{\xi_1}| \leq k) \\
&=\frac{2}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} j P(j-1<|{\xi_1}| \leq n) \\
&\leq \frac{2}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} j P(j-1<|{\xi_1}|) \\
&=\frac{2}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1) P(j<|{\xi_1}|) \\
&\leq \frac{4}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j P(|{\xi_1}|>j) \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
since $nP(|\xi_1|>n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$ Hence we deduce that $P(|T'_n - a_n|>\varepsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$

Combine the above two parts to show that $P(|T_n - a_n|>\varepsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Ty for anwer, but n^2P(\xi<n) -> infinity? Or not?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the solution. I stole the idea from Allan Gut's graduate level Probability book, you might look up the chapter on law of large numbers there.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt.

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\Pr\left(|\xi_1|>n\right)=0$, it must be that $\Pr(|\xi_1|>n)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

The expected value $E\left(\frac{\bar \xi}n\right)=E(\xi_1)$ and we also have that $a_n=E\left(\xi_11_{|\xi_1|<n}\right)=E(\xi_1)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

From Chebyshev's inequality (assuming finite variance) $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pr\left(|\bar \xi-a_n|>\epsilon\right)\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb V(\bar \xi)}{\epsilon^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb V(\xi_1)}{n\epsilon^2}=0$$

Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pr\left(|\bar \xi-a_n|<\epsilon\right)\ge1$$ and we have convergence in probability.